# There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

So here I have the html file, with the form for editing my users, all seems to work nice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body >

<div align="center">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/users/save}" th:method="POST" th:object="${user}">
        <table class="table center">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{user.id}" />

                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Username</th>
                    <td>

                            <input type="text"
                                     th:field="*{username}" />

                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>


                    <td>

                        <input type="text"/>

                    </td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Enabled</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               th:field="*{enabled}">

                    </td>


                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Role</td>
                   <td>
                       <ol th:each="role:${roleList}">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked
                            th:field="*{user.roles}"
                            th:value="${role.id}">
                            <label th:text="${role.getName()}"></label>
                        </div>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Update</input></td></tr>



        </table>
    </form>

</div>

<a th:href="${'/users'}"><input type="button" class="bg-warning bg-gradient btn btn-primary"
       th:value="Back"
        /></a>
</input>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller with the post mapping:

```
package com.florin.restaurant.controller;


import com.florin.restaurant.model.Menu;
import com.florin.restaurant.role.Role;
import com.florin.restaurant.service.IUserDetailsService;
import com.florin.restaurant.service.RoleService;
import com.florin.restaurant.user.User;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.AttributeNames;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.Mappings;
import com.florin.restaurant.util.ViewNames;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(Mappings.USERS_ID)
public class EditUserController {

    private final IUserDetailsService userService;
    private final RoleService roleService;


    @ModelAttribute(AttributeNames.USER)
    protected UserDetails modelUser(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
       List<Role> roleList = roleService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("roleList", roleList);
        return Optional.ofNullable(userService.findUserById(id)).get();
    }


    @GetMapping
    public String show(){

        return ViewNames.EDIT_USER;
    }


    @PostMapping (value = Mappings.USERS_SAVE)
    public String saveEdit(@Validated User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return ViewNames.EDIT_USER;
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "users";
    }

}
```

And this is the pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.florin.restaurant</groupId>
        <artifactId>restaurant</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    </parent>
    <groupId>com.florin.restaurant</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.florin.restaurant</groupId>
            <artifactId>game-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build><plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins></build>


</project>
```

It just keeps telling me that the post method is not allowed. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this? I want to update my users from the database, I just can't figure out why the post is not working... I also have the http.csrf().disable() in my WebConfig class.

Comment: Hey! What is the content of your Mappings.USER_ID constant?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ModelAttribute annotation:

`public String saveEdit(@ModelAttribute @Validated User user, BindingResult bindingResult)`